# Left- and right inverse, simple category theory proof

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory

> Let $f,g,h$ be morphisms in a category $C$, for which hold $gf=\operatorname{id}$ and $fh=\operatorname{id}$. Show that $f$ is an isomorphism and $g=h$.

A morphism $f: X\to Y$ in a category $C$ is an isomorphism when there is a morphism $g: Y\to X$ which holds: $gf=\operatorname{id}_X$ and $fg=\operatorname{id}_Y$.

When I can show, that $g=h$, then $f$ is automatically an isormorphism, because it has this property.

It is $g=g\operatorname{id}=g(fh)=(gf)h=\operatorname{id}h=h$

Comment: So what is it that you cannot show? The whole proof is in your post.

Comment: I am just asking for confirmation, or a proof verification.

Comment: Oh -- then yes, it's a perfectly valid proof! (I suggest saying that you want a proof verification explicitly in the text; I don't always look at the tags.)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the text ended up pretty short. Sorry, normally I do better, I guess...